# Umbraco: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: umbraco8

I am using Umbraco 8.4 version and my website is running on the azure app service. I have cloned the existing website and database and published it on another azure app service. When I open the website, I am getting the below error.

```
Boot failed: Umbraco cannot run. See Umbraco's log file for more details.

-> Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException: Boot failed.

-> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.IsStartElement()
  at Umbraco.Core.Services.Implement.LocalizedTextServiceFileSources.<.ctor>b__6_0()
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
  at Umbraco.Core.Services.Implement.LocalizedTextService.Localize(String key, CultureInfo culture, IDictionary`2 tokens)
  at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueListConfigurationEditor..ctor(ILocalizedTextService textService)
  at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.CheckBoxListPropertyEditor.CreateConfigurationEditor()
  at Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.DataEditor.GetConfigurationEditor()
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.DataType..ctor(IDataEditor editor, Int32 parentId)
  at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Factories.DataTypeFactory.BuildEntity(DataTypeDto dto, PropertyEditorCollection editors, ILogger logger)
  at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.DataTypeRepository.<PerformGetAll>b__3_1(DataTypeDto x)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.DataTypeRepository.PerformGetAll(Int32[] ids)
  at Umbraco.Core.Cache.DefaultRepositoryCachePolicy`2.GetAll(TId[] ids, Func`2 performGetAll)
  at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.RepositoryBase`2.GetMany(TId[] ids)
  at Umbraco.Core.Services.Implement.DataTypeService.GetAll(Int32[] ids)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentTypeFactory.GetDataType(Int32 id)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedPropertyType..ctor(String propertyTypeAlias, Int32 dataTypeId, Boolean isUserProperty, ContentVariation variations, PropertyValueConverterCollection propertyValueConverters, IPublishedModelFactory publishedModelFactory, IPublishedContentTypeFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedPropertyType..ctor(IPublishedContentType contentType, PropertyType propertyType, PropertyValueConverterCollection propertyValueConverters, IPublishedModelFactory publishedModelFactory, IPublishedContentTypeFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentTypeFactory.CreatePropertyType(IPublishedContentType contentType, PropertyType propertyType)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentType.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0(PropertyType x)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentType..ctor(IContentTypeComposition contentType, IPublishedContentTypeFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentTypeFactory.CreateContentType(IContentTypeComposition contentType)
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService.<LoadContentFromLocalDbLocked>b__37_0(IContentType x)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.ContentStore.SetAllContentTypesLocked(IEnumerable`1 types)
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService.LoadContentFromLocalDbLocked(Boolean onStartup)
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService.<LoadCachesOnStartup>b__27_0(IScope scope)
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService.LockAndLoadContent(Func`2 action)
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService.LoadCachesOnStartup()
  at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedSnapshotService..ctor(PublishedSnapshotServiceOptions options, IMainDom mainDom, IRuntimeState runtime, ServiceContext serviceContext, IPublishedContentTypeFactory publishedContentTypeFactory, IdkMap idkMap, IPublishedSnapshotAccessor publishedSnapshotAccessor, IVariationContextAccessor variationContextAccessor, IProfilingLogger logger, IScopeProvider scopeProvider, IDocumentRepository documentRepository, IMediaRepository mediaRepository, IMemberRepository memberRepository, IDefaultCultureAccessor defaultCultureAccessor, IDataSource dataSource, IGlobalSettings globalSettings, IEntityXmlSerializer entitySerializer, IPublishedModelFactory publishedModelFactory, UrlSegmentProviderCollection urlSegmentProviders)
  at DynamicMethod(Object[] )
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass150_0.<WrapAsFuncDelegate>b__0()
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass198_0.<EmitLifetime>b__1()
  at LightInject.PerContainerLifetime.GetInstance(Func`1 createInstance, Scope scope)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__1(IEmitter methodSkeleton)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependencies(ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, IEmitter emitter, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceUsingImplementingType(IEmitter emitter, ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitMethod)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceWithDecorators(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__2(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass198_0.<EmitLifetime>b__1()
  at LightInject.PerContainerLifetime.GetInstance(Func`1 createInstance, Scope scope)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__1(IEmitter methodSkeleton)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependencies(ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, IEmitter emitter, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceUsingImplementingType(IEmitter emitter, ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitMethod)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceWithDecorators(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__2(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass198_0.<EmitLifetime>b__1()
  at LightInject.PerContainerLifetime.GetInstance(Func`1 createInstance, Scope scope)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__1(IEmitter methodSkeleton)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependency(IEmitter emitter, Dependency dependency)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitConstructorDependencies(ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, IEmitter emitter, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceUsingImplementingType(IEmitter emitter, ConstructionInfo constructionInfo, Action`1 decoratorTargetEmitMethod)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstance(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitNewInstanceWithDecorators(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__0(IEmitter methodSkeleton)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean throwError)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.LightInject.LightInjectContainer.GetInstance(Type type)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.ComponentCollectionBuilder.CreateItem(IFactory factory, Type itemType)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.CollectionBuilderBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<CreateItems>b__0(Type x)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.CollectionBuilderBase`3.CreateItems(IFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.ComponentCollectionBuilder.CreateItems(IFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.CollectionBuilderBase`3.CreateCollection(IFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.LightInject.LightInjectContainer.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<Register>b__0(IServiceFactory f)
  at DynamicMethod(Object[] )
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass150_0.<WrapAsFuncDelegate>b__0()
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass198_0.<EmitLifetime>b__1()
  at LightInject.PerContainerLifetime.GetInstance(Func`1 createInstance, Scope scope)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.EmitLifetime(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration, Action`1 emitMethod, IEmitter emitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass197_0.<ResolveEmitMethod>b__1(IEmitter methodSkeleton)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.<>c__DisplayClass153_0.<CreateEmitMethodWrapper>b__0(IEmitter ms)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDynamicMethodDelegate(Action`1 serviceEmitter)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean throwError)
  at LightInject.ServiceContainer.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
  at Umbraco.Core.Composing.LightInject.LightInjectContainer.GetInstance(Type type)
  at Umbraco.Core.FactoryExtensions.GetInstance[T](IFactory factory)
  at Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.Boot(IRegister register, DisposableTimer timer)
```

I have checked all the configs files of Umbraco but was not able to troubleshoot the error.

Thanks
Imran Khan

Comment: I'm seeing the same errors and the /umbraco backoffice is not loading.  It says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.  v8.12.2 hosted dev server in AWS EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs, your problem looks like a caching issue and your v8 umbraco website can't get the data from NuCache.

Regenerating the cache data might solve your problem.

I don't know much about NuCache but here is the Umbraco documentation for [caching](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/cache/) and [here is a blog post](https://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2018/07/30/peek-inside-umbraco-v8-nucache-files-with-the-nucache-explorer-tool/) about NuCache and how to explore it.